# MySQL Update error with select

Tags: mysql

My below MySQL is giving error.

```
UPDATE P SET P.author_name = A.name 
FROM POSTS AS P INNER JOIN AUTHORS AS A
ON P.author_id = A.id;

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FROM POSTS AS P INNER JOIN AUTHORS AS A
ON P.author_id = A.id' at line 2
```

However, select works fine.

```
select P.id, a.name
FROM POSTS AS P INNER JOIN AUTHORS AS A
ON P.author_id = A.id;
```

I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong, any help?

Comment: Your update looks correct for TSql.  This link shows a different syntax for MySql - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

Comment: the SET needs to goes after the INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql, you'll need to code the `JOIN` first, and then the `SET` statement:

```
UPDATE POSTS INNER JOIN AUTHORS ON POSTS.author_id = AUTHOR.id
SET POSTS.author_name = AUTHOR.name
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I got it from the comment by Joe C. I will accept your answer when SO will allow me after 8 mins.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE POSTS 
INNER JOIN AUTHORS ON POSTS.author_id = AUTHORS.id;
SET POSTS.author_name = AUTHORS.name
```

Comment: This answer lacks an explanation.